# regex equal or greater than the number 3

Tags: javascript, php, regex, validation

i been searching the net for a while without any success. i appreciate if anyone can solve this problem or at least point me to the right direction.

i need a regular expression pattern that does the following:

- equal or greater than the number 3
- must not allow decimals
- must not allow negative numbers

i am using foundation 5 abide.js to validate my form and this requires a regex pattern for advanced validation.
this is required to validate a price input field.

Comment: why regex? you have JS.

Comment: Regex only? Much easier to convert to a number and check your constraints

Comment: Regexes cannot calculate, so you have to express "greater than 3" in terms of characters and strings.

Comment: Also, you specified the minimum, how about the max? Is `12348712983470` a valid price?

Comment: there is no maximum, this is going to be used for a donation form so there shouldn't be any constraints on the maximum

Comment: I love the way OPs selectively disregard questions.

Comment: Regex is not the only way, you can use validadors

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html

Comment: @KarolyHorvath The OP did reply  about the maximum and explained why regex, Error: invalid sarcasm. Although I hope they read my comment, because regex for this is so the wrong solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can read in comments, regex is not the appropriate tool to deal with numbers. However you can use this pattern:

```
^(?:[3-9]|[12]\d)\d*$
```

Note: if you want to allow leading zeros, you only need to add `0*` at the begining:

```
^0*(?:[3-9]|[12]\d)\d*$
```

Comment: Note that abide.js does allow custom validators as functions http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html

Answer (score 3):

you could use this pattern  `^(?![012]$)\d+$`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bL9nN6/2)

here is another one for the leading zeros `^(?!0*[012]$)\d+$`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bL9nN6/4)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, care to explain why it is "incorrect"?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Just saying is incorrect doesn't help, please post the case where it fails instead of saying "please don't upvote it"

Comment: @alphabravo: it was the leading zeros (the example was in my first comment). as you fixed it after my second comment, I have no idea why you're doing this (well, I have, but...) note: removing comment, as it is not relevant now.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath in response to your comment : 'I have no idea why you're doing this', you have no idea why I'm doing what??